# asp.net cookie from a resource project (+ a general info)

Tags: c#, asp.net, class

i'd like to use a class to manage a certain cookie, but not directly on the page where i have access to all the **httpcookie** stuff like so `HttpContext.Current.Request.Cookies["CookieName"].Value;`.

however i'd like to be able to do this from a class in another project. i have a reference to that project and can access the class, but there i do not have access to the **httpcontext**.

so how do i get access to that, and how can i generally access all the stuff in an outside class that i can on the page directly?

the reason for this is that this code is common and will be used on a lot of pages, so don't want to have it in multiple places.

*thnx*
***i hope i explained it correctly, ask if you need more info.***

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add the System.Web assembly reference to your class library project and use:

`System.Web.HttpContext.Current` to get access to the HttpContext, from within any of your classes in your library.